# Burninate the [carray] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I think that the [carray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/carray) tag should be burninated as

- I don't see how [carray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/carray) is different/special from [arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrays).
- There aren't tags such as [java-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-array),[c++-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-array) etc
- Each language might have a different way for defining, declaring and initializing an array, but that does not mean that each language needs a different tag for arrays.

What's your opinion? Should it be burninated or not?

Comment: As there are only five questions this shouldn't be too difficult to do.

Comment: Looks like someone retagged the rest of the questions. There were more questions tagged with it earlier, IIRC.

Comment: I read the tag as "canary" the first time and thought "this should be renamed as, "Send the [canary] to the Coal Mine." Then I read the post and was sad.