# Should [google-apps-script-simple-triggers] and [gs-installable-triggers] be scrapped in favor of [google-apps-script]+[triggers]?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

Google apps script is a  scripting language based on JavaScript to automate Google products  like Google sheets. The script can be triggered in various ways  based on time of day, a edit in a spreadsheet, opening the spreadsheet, etc. The difference between "simple" [google-apps-script-simple-triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-simple-triggers) "installable" [gs-installable-triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gs-installable-triggers) triggers lie primarily in authorization/permission contexts. Detailed guide [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers).

**Why favor scrapping?**

- **<sup>★NEW★</sup>** Precedents For:

  - [[tag:excel-vba] vs [tag:excel]+[tag:vba]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393153) - Combo tag bites the dust
  - [[tag:arrays] vs [tag:carray]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287045) - Combo tag cleaned up
  - [[tag:ms-access-forms] vs [tag:ms-access]+[tag:forms]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399320/disambiguate-all-ms-access-questions)- Combo tag proposal declined
- **<sup>★NEW★</sup>** Precedents Against: Though there are 40+ [*trigger*] tags, it's very rare(<5) to see a `[language-trigger]` tag(like [c#-trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-trigger)). And it's unheard of to use a combo `[language-typeOfTrigger-trigger]` tag. I can't find any precedents for this combo.
- **<sup>★NEW★</sup>**  Only one user added this tag to more than 70% of all questions with this tag. Data [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1264905/1557920/who-added-this-tag-to-the-question)  and [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1264912/1557927/percent-of-users-who-added-this-tag). I myself account for a additional ~10%(I was  naive). For popular tags like [triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/triggers) or [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), no user's contribution crossed 5%.

  - Tag creation and retagging are  done without discussion with the community or meta post.
  - Any of the other active users with >10k reps did not add this tag to questions(except myself).
  - If this user quits SO, then tags will be split and rest of the users will be burdened with retagging done by one user.
- Actual harm: As the highly specific tags do not have enough watchers, questions were simply ignored, if not tagged with [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) as well.
- The differences between "simple" and "installable" trigger(Which is  primarily authorization) doesn't warrant a division between these tags.
- Although [triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/triggers) can't be standalone, [google-apps-script-simple-triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-simple-triggers) can't be used standalone either, due to the low number of watchers.
- A perfectly valid alternative: [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) + [triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/triggers) exists.
- "*[triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/triggers) looks like a meta tag*". [No it isn't](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/399493/). Even if it is(which it isn't), data suggests [combo tags does  the same, if not more harm](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/399536/) by splitting up watchers and answerers.

**Some more stats:**

**[google-apps-script-simple-triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-simple-triggers)**:

- It has 131 questions(as of last Sunday). [Of which 111 questions did not have the tag in the initial post by the initial poster](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1264006/1556796/how-many-questions-tagged-with-tag-in-retag#resultSets) - suggesting that almost 85% of the questions were the result of retagging efforts by tag editors.
- It currently has 10 watchers. With only 10 watchers and the question is about the programming language [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script), questions which are only tagged with this tag are actively hidden from the experts  watching at [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script). Valid questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60257557/triggers-are-not-firing)(with only 5 views at the time of this post) are completely missed, thus actively causing harm.

**[gs-installable-triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gs-installable-triggers)**:

- The case is much worse  with this tag.  First, the prefix `gs` is ambiguous- It may mean Google sheets like [gs-vlookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gs-vlookup) or [gs-conditional-formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gs-conditional-formatting)
- It has a total of 98 questions, of which 78 were added after edits and not present initially.
- It currently has 1 watcher.

**[google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script)+[triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/triggers)**:

- There is a total of 465 questions currently tagged with both these tags.

Should these tags exist?

Comment: I think that for the sake of uniformity and complexity neither of the `google-apps-script` trigger tags are needed. I'd be more than happy to do away with them and just have tags built from `google-apps-script` and `triggers`. The GAS trigger-specific tags unnecessarity segregate these questions from `triggers` questions and just increases the change of the questions being missed (I for one would never see a question simply tagged `gs-installable-triggers` if it wasn't for the inclusion of `google-apps-script` as well).

Comment: The `gs-` prefix for `google-apps-script` tag branches should be completely abolished anyway, there is a huge relationship between `google-sheets` and `google-apps-script` but they do not always correlate, *especially* as there exist `google-sheets` specific triggers.

Comment: If the information contained in the wiki of those two tags can be combined, generalized a little and moved to the [tag:triggers] tag (which I think is more than doable), I would also agree that removing GAS duplication from the tag and subsequent merge will only benefit the questions regarding triggers.

Comment: @Rubén Meta tag by definition [The reason meta-tags are a problem is that they do not describe the content of the question. They describe some other aspect of the question, like the author’s skill level, or the author’s motivation for asking it, or generally what “kind” of question it is (poll, how-to, etc.)](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/). None of these characteristics  apply to [tag:triggers]

Comment: @Rubén That's not the only criteria for meta tag. See Cody answer here: [The problem with number 2 is a simple misunderstanding of what was meant by a "meta tag". Consistent with the definition of the Greek-derived prefix, "meta", a "meta tag" is one that describes the nature or type of a question, rather than its content. Examples of meta tags are homework, beginner, interesting, urgent, programming, unanswered, and so on. It is not as simple as "a tag that cannot stand alone as a question's sole tag"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356080)

Comment: @Rubén Irrelevant. I'm only defining "meta-tag" as defined in one of those answers. [tag:triggers] fails  the criteria to  be defined as a meta tag. Can it be used standalone? Of course not. Does that mean it's a meta tag? No. Why not? Here are some examples provided by Cody: *Examples of meta tags are homework, beginner, interesting, urgent, programming, unanswered, and so on*. **It is not as simple as "a tag that cannot stand alone as a question's sole tag"**. What then is a meta tag?  *a "meta tag" is one that describes the nature or type of a question, rather than its content*.

Comment: Does [tag:triggers] describes the **nature** or **type** of question rather than it's **content**? No. That's why it's not a meta tag.

Comment: @Rubén Pragmatically speaking, due to the number of watchers, [tag:google-apps-script-simple-triggers] cannot be used as a standalone tag either. Theoretically speaking, Yes it can be. But practically, No. [Classic example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60257557/triggers-are-not-firing)- Near 0 views, no comments on how to improve the question.

Comment: @TheMaster As I don't like the "Watch" feature so much I'm using it for very few tags but I'm still reviewing frequently other tags including the tags that are being suggested to be scrapped.

Comment: @Rubén It's a indicator of how many people are interested are in the tag and not a absolute. I understand that. But it is a "relative" indicator of actual watchers. If tag1 has 10 and tag2 has 100 watchers, real number ratio will also be close to 10:100 or 1:10

Comment: Regarding the "new" stats they are missing to show how many question that have added the "harmful" tags by that single user that doesn't include [tag:google-apps-script]. By the other hand, it could be interesting to know how many of the [tag:triggers] experts answer have answered a question about Google Apps Script triggers.

Comment: @Rubén The tag is harmful, because it is artificially inflated by one user(i.e., you :)).If such a tag is then suggested to new users, it'll be unanswered because the product tag is missed as the example I've shown above. I'm sure you wouldn't have missed adding the product tag. So, if I make that query, it'll probably be 0%. That's irrelevant though as the problem is artificial inflation by 1 user. If you leave or take a break or decide not to watch the tag anymore, many questions may be hidden unnecessarily. The precedents prove the general consensus against such combined tags.

Comment: @Rubén *how many of the triggers experts answer have answered a question about Google Apps Script triggers.* That's irrelevant too. I'm advocating [triggers]+[g-a-s] and not  just [triggers]. I'm not quite sure what the point here is. Are you doing this for badges in apps script-triggers tag or something?

Comment: I'm adding the tags for making it easier to find questions about simple and installable triggers, nothing else. I don't thing that gas+triggers is better, actually, as I already mentioned I think that triggers is not a good tag.

Comment: The arguments described in favor of gas + triggers so far looks to me "artificial" Why did you not proposed gas + web-application when gas-web-apps was discussed few days earlier?

Comment: @Rubén *The arguments described so far looks to me "artificial"* With only 136 questions and >80% tagged artificially, I think the classic example provided itself provides "substance"/"proof" and makes it "real". That would be 2 questions out of around 27 original questions.

Comment: *Why did you not proposed gas + web-application when gas-web-apps was discussed few days earlier?* Main reason is We just  created/synonimized [gas-web-app]. I didn't think It was right to take a U-turn right after without seeing the merits of the case. Going against you in triggers is a exhausting job in itself. I'll see how it goes here, research and come back to web-apps, if I wish :)

Comment: @Rubén To be clear, That would be 2 questions that's tagged with only [g-a-s-s-t], that you missed in your watch out of around 27 questions tagged with [g-a-s-s-t] + [g-a-s] naturally by users without artificial retag(around 7%). Think about it. It'll be unmaintanable in the future, if this picks up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Although [triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/triggers) was not a bad tag per se, It is not a standalone tag and Synonymizing [google-apps-script-simple-triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-simple-triggers) to [triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/triggers) caused issues where new users would simply tag [google-apps-script-simple-triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-simple-triggers) and it would change to [triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/triggers) and question is left unattended.

It was therefore decided by the community to synonymize both these tags ([google-apps-script-simple-triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-simple-triggers) and [gs-installable-triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gs-installable-triggers)) to the parent tag [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script)  instead to get rid off the tags and to keep users from recreating the tag and making the same mistake again.

Comment: Special  thanks to moderator @Bhargav [mod-link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4099593/bhargav-rao) for helping with  the original synonym-removal

Answer (score 1):

1. No, they should not be scrapped in favor of a tag combination that includes [triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/triggers) because this tag is already being discussed (was discussed (Feb 2019)?) -> [Should the [triggers] tag exist?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380204/1595451) and so far the consensus is that [triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/triggers) **is not a good tag**.

Rather than scrapping [google-apps-script-simple-triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-simple-triggers) and [gs-installable-triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gs-installable-triggers) "follow" them as well as follow [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) and [triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/triggers). Actually rather that "watch" you might find more convenient to create a custom filter

---

2. No, they should not be scrapped in favor of a tag combination that includes [triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/triggers) because using a "combination" rather than a single tag makes it harder for experts on that tag to find questions.

---

Fun facts:

1. Searching for `[*trigger*]` the [results page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/*trigger*) shows 20 tags.
   These are the tags returned by the SO search page:

   [triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/triggers) or [database-trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database-trigger) or [datatrigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatrigger) or
   [trigger.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/trigger.io) or [eventtrigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eventtrigger) or [crontrigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/crontrigger) or
   [google-apps-script-simple-triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-simple-triggers) or [gerrit-trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gerrit-trigger) or
   [multidatatrigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multidatatrigger) or [gs-installable-triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gs-installable-triggers) or
   [updatesourcetrigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/updatesourcetrigger) or [azure-webjobs-triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-webjobs-triggered) or
   [azure-triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-triggers) or [ddl-trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ddl-trigger) or [jquery-trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-trigger) or
   [build-triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/build-triggers) or [multitrigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multitrigger) or
   [unnotificationtrigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unnotificationtrigger) or [apex-trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apex-trigger) or
   [timer-trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/timer-trigger)
2. The [Tags page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) shows >30 tags
3. The 21-26 tags having `trigger` (not included in the above list) are:
   [amazon-cognito-triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-cognito-triggers), [azure-blog-trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-blog-trigger), [queuetrigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/queuetrigger), [jenkings-jira-trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jenkings-jira-trigger), [postresql-triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postresql-triggers). All of them have between 17 and 30 questions.
4. I'm ~middle of the list of the All Time Top answerers of [google-apps-script-simple-triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-simple-triggers)
5. I'm at the top five of the list of the All Time Top answerers of [gs-installable-triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gs-installable-triggers)

Related

- [Observing new questions of combination of union and intersections of tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267205/1595451)
- [custom-questions-list](/questions/tagged/custom-questions-list)

Comment: There is no consensus.  It wasn't even a burninate request, but a discussion as it failed all 4 criteria in OP's own words. Only(@jpmc) agrees that it should be burnt-with 9 upvotes and 6 downvotes. @Makoto was against combined tags([tag:database-trigger]) in particular, and just wants to clean up. In hindsight, it was the combined tag: [tag:database-triggers] that was burninated instead of [tag:triggers], which exists with a very specific usage guideline compatible with [tag:google-apps-script].

Comment: Not all bad tags should be burninated because the effort that it implies. It's just expected that users who are aware of bad tags don't use them and that while they are editing a question remove the bad tags.

Comment: I don't think its a **bad tag** either. I link [my answer there here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/399493/). I don't see any reason that it's bad. A similar example would be the tag [tag:arrays]. It's not a standalone tag, frequently used across multiple products and languages.

Comment: I don't think that [tag:arrays] and [tag:triggers] are comparable (anyway, there are a lot  of tags having `array`,  ~40)

Comment: I gave two examples in which they are comparable: 1. Both represents concepts common in almost all programming languages. 2.  Both tags cannot be used standalone, but only as builder tags. >Even if there are 40 related array* tags, we don't have java-array, c-array, c++-array. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287045 In a similar way, we don't need a programming specific trigger tag.