# Deprecation clause in small tag description

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, suggested-edits

I have a question about [this proposed edit for tag](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/34574455) [react-mui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-mui).

Basically it introduces a "deprecation" clause into tag.

While I believe this might be a valid approach for tags that are saved for historical reasons, this tag has only one question tagged with it. Additionally, that single question is already tagged with the proposed new tag too.

Shouldn't this tag [react-mui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-mui) be simply deleted instead?

Comment: I removed the tag from that question. Probably the editor didn't know how to delete the tag (need to wait for the daily clean-up script to completely prune the tag).

Comment: @AndrewT. is it daily? I thought that tag without questions will be deleted only after a couple of months.

Comment: @markalex it's daily; anything that takes longer than that (unless there were new questions with the tag where it was removed after the script ran) requires manual intervention due to an as-yet-unresolved bug.

Answer (score 14):

To be clear, The product that is referred by the tag seems to be [React MUI](https://mui.com/), which is not deprecated.

I think what the proposed edit intends to do, is to suggest users to use combination tag [react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react)[material-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/material-ui) instead of a hyphenated tag [react-mui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-mui). I think that's a good suggestion. The author also clearly says he's doing this because he cannot delete the tag. However, the best course of action, in such cases, is to bring the deletion request to meta instead of editing the tag excerpt.

The tag in question should be burninated, without following the full burnination protocol.

---

Based on consensus,

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[image: 1]

Comment: Oh, didn't mean that product is deprecated, only tag.

Comment: This tag appears to have ended up stuck, so I've resolved that by merging it into [[tag:material-ui]] and creating a synonym (EDIT: synonym removed; see later discussion in this comment thread).

Comment: @RyanM Apologies for bothering this with you again. But I've been thinking.. wouldn't [reactjs] be a better target for the synonym instead of [material-ui]?  The problem with synonymizing to [material-ui] is it has considerably less number of watchers(react has like 100 times more). So, if a user tags [react-mui] alone, thinking he alerted both react and mui community, and the system silently changes to [material-ui], the  intended majority tag is lost. Thoughts? Think  this will be a issue? (Old history: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/401153/)

Comment: @TheMaster That's a good point.   Maybe we should just remove the synonym entirely in the hopes that they would then add both tags?

Comment: @RyanM Yes. I think that's the best solution.

Comment: @TheMaster Sounds good.  Done.